# how to animate "simple jquery filtering" by using css only

Tags: javascript, css, sorting, animation, filtering

I'm trying to animate the elements when they are filtered by javascript but the codes below don't work. Any suggestion? 
This is what I have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/ejkim2000/J7TF4/

```
$("#ourHolder").css("animation","scaleUp 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards");

$("#ourHolder").css({"animation" : "scaleDown 0.3s linear 0.4s forwards"});
```

On second thought, is there any other way that I can animate the elements by using css only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do it using CSS transitions. I believe this is what you're trying to do, but I can't find the referenced 'scaleDown' animation anywhere. My solution animates both width and height of the .item elements when toggling an additional '.hidden' class on them:

```
#ourHolder div.item.hidden {
    transition: all 0.3s linear
}

#ourHolder div.item.hidden {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Full solution on http://jsfiddle.net/5pKwy/

**EDIT: Fiddle using min-height and min-width:** http://jsfiddle.net/5pKwy/1/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply. This works perfectly. However, is there any way that I can use transition without using specific width and height in "#ourHolder div.item"

Comment: No, since the transition affects the dimensions of the element, there must be a dimension specified to begin with. However, nothing stops you from using relative width, i.e. 25% instead of 200.

Comment: On second thought, you can. There has to be some width and height involved, but you can easily solve that using `min-width` and `min-height`. As in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5pKwy/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nicklas. This will do. I appreciate it.